# NoClassDefFoundError with klio-mobile-dataservice on Android

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to implement [klio's library](http://code.google.com/p/klio-mobile-dataservice/wiki/HOWTOSample), but I keep on getting this exception, even following the tutorial.

Here's the logcat:

```
    11-12 23:34:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27299): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-12 23:34:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27299): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: flex.messaging.io.amf.client.AMFConnection
    11-12 23:34:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at tiwiz.connection.test.ConnectionActivity.retrieveNetData(ConnectionActivity.java:72)
    11-12 23:34:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at tiwiz.connection.test.ConnectionActivity.onCreate(ConnectionActivity.java:32)
    11-12 23:34:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    11-12 23:34:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    11-12 23:34:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
    11-12 23:34:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)
    11-12 23:34:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)
    11-12 23:34:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
    11-12 23:34:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    11-12 23:34:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    11-12 23:34:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
    11-12 23:34:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-12 23:34:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    11-12 23:34:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
    11-12 23:34:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
    11-12 23:34:30.979: E/AndroidRuntime(27299):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Compiling goes well, so it looks like it finds classes during compile process...
Can someone help me? :)

Comment: if you are trying to run it on device, you may be using it to compile but not deploying the resource.

Comment: Have you ensured classpath runtime config correctly?

Comment: What do you mean? I added it as reference from Project -> Properties -> Project References and signed it for export in Order and Export tab, shall I do something else I'm not aware of? Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get klio-mobile-dataservice to work?  I am currently have an issue where MyService.MyMethod call isn't working.  Also trying to not sure how to add my own custom classes to be serialized and unserialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to a change in how libraries are managed in ADT, starting from version 17.

[This](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17) is the solution, essentially:

1. remove the *KlioMobileDS* project from your Java Build Path
2. export it into .jar
3. put that .jar into your project **libs** folder

Comment: Same as above, but now I can't see it under libraries, it's under Android Dependencies.

Comment: Tested again and now it works, I forgot to clean everything in the project. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check whether there is a libs folder inside your project. If not create it and add all your external libraries to it. Then import those libraries from this libs folder to your buildpath. That's it. If the problem remains go to Order and Export tab in Build Path and move all libraries you imported to the Top.